# Flask Catch SQLite Query Issues

Tags: python, json, sqlite, http, flask

I'm writing an API in Flask, and my HTTP `DELETE` method deletes a record in SQLite according to its ID passed as a JSON.

Assuming the ID passed does not exist, no error is thrown and success 200 is returned. Is that the expected behaviour? Should I throw an HTTP error? If so, how can I check if `db.execute()` query did not finish properly?

Sorry but this is my first time writing an API in Flask and I'm still learning it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`sqlite3.Cursor`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor) object has a [`rowcount`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount) attribute that will be greater than or equal to 1 if the ID existed.

Alternately, since [`DELETE` is idempotent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) you *could* assume that every ID you are provided *was* valid at some point and always return a 200 or 204 (although a 404 is better if the resource never could have existed).